# Is this output correct? or is it an error?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, exception, nullpointerexception

I just want to make sure what I am receiving from an Eclipse is an error, or it's fine? 
Here is my code:

```
package prj2;

public class Sandbox {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NodeChain<Integer> myList = new NodeChain<Integer>();

        myList.add(1); 
        myList.add(2); 
        myList.add(0, -99); 
        myList.add(3, 45);
        myList.add(99);
        myList.add(4, 50);

        myList.remove(0);
        myList.remove(3);
        myList.remove(1);

        System.out.println(myList.contains(45));

        myList.print();
        System.out.println("myList has size "+myList.size());
    }

}
```

And here is the result:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at prj2.NodeChain.contains(NodeChain.java:57)
    at prj2.Sandbox.main(Sandbox.java:18)
```

If that's an error can you please help for a fix?

Source for NodeChain:

```
package prj2;

public class NodeChain<E> implements ListADT<E>{
    private ListNode<E> head; // this is a dummy header 
    private ListNode<E> tail;
    private int numItems;

    public NodeChain() {
        head = new ListNode<E>(null);
        tail = head;
        numItems = 0;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() { return numItems == 0; }

    public void add(E item) { 
        // Note the lack of a need for null checks
        tail.setNext(new ListNode<E>(item, tail.getNext()));
        tail = tail.getNext();
        numItems++;
    }

    public void add(int pos, E item) {
        // Handle the cases where an invalid pos is given
        if (pos < 0 || pos > numItems) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();

        // Handle the case where we're adding to the end of the list.
        if (pos == numItems) {
            add(item);
            return;
        }

        // No other special case handling required
        // Traverse the list until we get to the point of insertion and execute the insertion.
        ListNode<E> tmp = traverseTo(pos);
        tmp.setNext(new ListNode<E>(item, tmp.getNext()));

        // Increment numItems
        numItems++;
    }

    public int size() { return numItems; }

    public E remove(int pos) { // Left unimplemented
        return null;
    }

    public E get(int pos) {
        if (pos < 0 || pos >= numItems) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        ListNode<E> node = traverseTo(pos+1);
        return node.getData();
    }

    public boolean contains(E obj) {
        ListNode<E> tmp = head;
        while (tmp != null) {
            if (tmp.getData().equals(obj)) return true;
            tmp = tmp.getNext();
        }
        return false;
    }

    private ListNode<E> traverseTo(int pos) {
        if (pos < 0 || pos >= numItems) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        ListNode<E> tmp = head;
        for (int i = 0; i < pos; i++) 
            tmp = tmp.getNext();
        return tmp;
    }

    /* Extra method to facilitate debugging */
    public void print() {
        ListNode<E> tmp = head;
        while (tmp != null) {
            System.out.print(tmp.getData()+", ");
            tmp = tmp.getNext();
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Source for ListNode:

```
package prj2;

public class ListNode<T> {
    private T data;
    private ListNode<T> next;

    public ListNode(T obj) {
        this(obj, null);
    }

    public ListNode(T obj, ListNode<T> ptr) {
        data = obj;
        next = ptr;
    }

    public void setData(T obj) { data = obj; }

    public T getData() { return data; }

    public void setNext(ListNode<T> n) { next = n; }

    public ListNode<T> getNext() { return next; }
}
```

Source for ListADT:

```
package prj2;

/**
 * A List is an ordered collection of items.
 */
public interface ListADT<E> {
    /**
     * Add item to the end of the List.
     *
     * @param item the item to add
     */
    void add(E item);

    /**
     * Add item at position pos in the List, moving the items
     * originally in positions pos through size()- 1 one place
     * to the right to make room.
     *
     * @param pos the position at which to add the item
     * @param item the item to add
     * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException if pos is less than 0
     * or greater than size()
     */
    void add(int pos, E item);

    /**
     * Return true iff item is
     * item x in the List such
     *
     * @param item the item to
     * @return true if item is
     */
    boolean contains(E item);

    /**
     * Return the number of items in the List.
     *
     * @return the number of items in the List
     */
    int size();

    /**
     * Return true iff the List is empty.
     *
     * @return true if the List is empty, false otherwise
     */
    boolean isEmpty();

    /**
     * Return the item at position pos in the List.
     *
     * @param pos the position of the item to return
     * @return the item at position pos
     * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException if pos is less than 0
     * or greater than or equal to size()
     */
    E get(int pos);

    /**
     * Remove and return the item at position pos in the List,
     * moving the items originally in positions pos+1 through
     * size() one place to the left to fill in the gap.
     *
     * @param pos the position at which to remove the item
     * @return the item at position pos
     * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException if pos is less than 0
     * or greater than or equal to size()
     */
    E remove(int pos);
}
```

Comment: It's an error and without the source for `NodeChain`, it's impossible to know why

Comment: The stacktrace seems to provide all the info you need.

Comment: I can't imagine many times where a `NullPointerException` + stack trace + program exit is the *correct* output for a program...

Comment: @MadProgrammer I added the rest of the code in the updated question. Can you please take a look?

Comment: @MadProgrammer What's wrong with this code? I don't quite get it? `public boolean contains(E obj) {
  ListNode<E> tmp = head;
  while (tmp != null) {
   if (tmp.getData().equals(obj)) return true;
   tmp = tmp.getNext();
  }
  return false;
 }`

Comment: This is going to be hard to explain, but, you create a `head` using `new ListNode<E>(null);`, which means when you call `getData` on it, it will return `null`.  You never reset this.  Instead, when you add a new element, you need to determine if there is anything already in your `NodeChain`, if there is not, you need make the node the head

Comment: This means that in your constructor, you should not be creating a `head` or `tail`, they should remain `null`.  When `add` is called, you need to check if `head` is `null`, if it is, you create a `new ListNode`, assign it to head and tail and the continue with the rest of the add process.  If `head` is not `null`, you simply need to create a new instance of the `ListNode` and proceed as normal...

Comment: I'm sorry, this is going to be messy, but you're using an IDE with auto formatting, it should just about fix it... `public void add(E item) {
    // Note the lack of a need for null checks
    ListNode<E> next = null;
    if (head == null) {
        head = new ListNode<E>(item);
        tail = head;
        next = head;
    } else {
        next = new ListNode<E>(item, tail.getNext());
    }
    tail.setNext(next);
    tail = tail.getNext();
    numItems++;
}`

Comment: @MadProgrammer got you. This code of mine fixed it thanks to your hint  `public void add(E item) { 
  // Note the lack of a need for null checks
  if (numItems==0){

   head = new ListNode<E>(item,null);
   tail=head;
   numItems++;
   
  }
  else{
  tail.setNext(new ListNode<E>(item, tail.getNext()));
  tail = tail.getNext();
  numItems++;
  }
 }`

Answer (score 1):

Well,it is clearly reflected from the output that it's an Exception thrown or rather `Error`.The exception thrown is `java.lang.NullPointerException`!

Also,the stack trace of what the error is about is printed below the Exception thrown line:-

```
at prj2.NodeChain.contains(NodeChain.java:57)
at prj2.Sandbox.main(Sandbox.java:18)
```

Also,it's clearly visible from your stack trace that there is an exception being thrown at `System.out.println(myList.contains(45));`.

You better resolve this error after checking your code of `contains()` method in `NodeClass` Class!